# Unity engine memory usage issue - taking up more than it should

Tags: unity, performance, optimization, memory, profiler

I'm making a 2D game that consists mostly of *sprites*. As a lot of them were too large in file size, I swapped them into *meshes with unlit materials **without** textures*. Now, The problem is that Unity by default, just opening a blank scene, uses **20 MB** of texture memory according to the profiler.

So I checked instantiating 100 of my sprites (294 kb each), where the profiler showed **100MB** used.

After that I had only those meshes in the scene, still 100 pieces, vertex count **124** each, tri count **47**. 
The memory usage was still around **100 MB**, texture usage **20 MB**

Lastly I instantiated 100-100, so the sprites and meshes together. 
I got around **106 MB** used memory.

This is my used memory with the **sprites**:
[image: memory with sprites]
And this is my used memory with the meshes.
[image]
Now, as far as I know the meshes should rock in terms of memory as they are low res and have no textures attached. 
Could someone tell me what's going on, why are my meshes worse than using sprites? And how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone reading this, I got help via Unity bug report and they revealed the the Profiler reflects *everything* regarding Unity, not just my game. The engineer made a build and profiled my game that way - the mesh setup is **waaay** more effective. Use that if you have the chance.